# How can I interact with python app in raspberry-pi through an android app?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a Python application that run on Raspberry device. The thing is, I want my android app to be able to control the function of that app. Let's says I set that function only work while a bool variable is true, so my android app would somehow interfere and turn that varialbe into false. Is this the right way to set up my case? If yes, what method or technology should I use to make it work? If not, what is the right way and how to make that way work? I'm sorry for asking plain question like this but I'm new to Python and Raspberry as well so I don't know the proper keyword or forum to look for answer.

Comment: What about writing a simple web interface (accessed by your phone(?)) which controls the app, and host this with Flask on you Pi.

Comment: The problem is I'm not looking for turn on/off Pi device nor closing and re-open the Python application. I want to disable/enable a function inside that application.

Comment: Yes. You can write an interface (in Flask) which interacts with that function / application.  Then the interface can listen for commands sent from the web UI, accessed by your phone.

Comment: Thank you. Do you perhaps know what kind of protocol I'm aiming to in this situation?